# Varying coefficeint of entropic linearized program, can we bound the change in solutions?

Tags: linear-programming, entropy

An entropic linearized program is defined as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll@{}ll}
\text{maximize}  & \displaystyle \langle c,x\rangle-\frac{1}{\eta}H(x) \\
\text{subject to}& \displaystyle Ax=b   \\                                                  
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
where $H(x)=\sum_{i=1}^d x_i\log x_i$, $\eta$ is a regularization parameter.

Suppose now that we have two different programs with different coefficients $c_1,c_2$, can we bound the distance of solution $x_1,x_2$ in terms of $c_1,c_2$?

Intuitively, when $c_1,c_2$ are close, the solution should not change too much, let alone having the entropic function to regularize it.